# SQL - Left Join - On part of string only

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm trying to make a Left Join, should be simple enough, I have 2 problems;

- The values are in Binary
- I need to Join the left 3 characters in one string to the right 3 characters of the other (after they are changed from binary)

Join, Left 3 characters of this one

```
convert(VARCHAR(max),(file_key7), 102)
```

in db `[RF_Sydney].[dbo].[std_file]`

with the Right 3 characters of this one

```
convert(VARCHAR(max),(code_key), 11)
```

in db `[RF_Sydney].[dbo].[std_code]`

Comment: Is database SQL Server or mysql?

Comment: The [dbo] artifact in the question indicates Sql Server. I removed the bad tag.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server, you can join on any condition that can be satisfied; in other words, you can do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.std_file f LEFT JOIN std_code c 
ON LEFT(convert(VARCHAR(max),(f.file_key7), 102), 3)
= RIGHT(convert(VARCHAR(max),(c.code_key), 11),3)
```

Performance will suck (unless you use persisted computed columns and define an index).

Comment: Thanks; please accept it as an answer so the question will be closed.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to use a [`computed column`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) in each of those tables. This will allow you to simplify your join code, and even allow you to define an index on the column to improve performance if you need it. As for getting the left and right value, there are LEFT() and RIGHT() functions you can use:

```
LEFT(convert(VARCHAR(max),(file_key7), 102), 3)
```

and

```
RIGHT(convert(VARCHAR(max),(code_key), 11), 3)
```

For the join expression and query itself, we don't have enough information yet to know exactly how you want these to fit together.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the length of file_key7 or code_key?  Joining LEFT(str,len) = RIGHT(str,len) should work but possible take a big performance hit.  Maybe you should create field/column and stick your partial keys in it already converted in the right character format